# Return a data from callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

```
    var myVar;    
    myModule.myFunction().then(function(data){
       myVar = data;     
    });
    console.log(myVar);
```

I have a module named `myModule` which exports a function `myFunction` with some promise. Now when I assign the data to `myVar`, and print it, it shows `undefined`. What will be the proper solution to achieve this result?

Comment: You are declaring myVar as undefined. Then assigning some data to myVar but in the meantime console.loging myVar. Make sure that the console log gets executed after the myVar = data by putting the console.log into the .then function right after myVar = data **Also check that data is not undefined**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @BenFortune, did you even read my question? I have already done whatever that solution says, but after the promise is returned, my control is blocked within the "then" block.

Comment: Clearly you haven't read the solutions. Scroll down to the promise solution by Benjamin Gruenbaum which is almost identical to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to reconsider your structure, but to achieve what you're asking for is to have the `console.log` inside the promise.

```
 var myVar;    
    myModule.myFunction().then(function(data){
       myVar = data;  
       console.log(myVar);   
    });
```

Comment: I have to use myVar outside that control. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted is not synchronous, so it is working correctly.

This is the flow of your code to give you a better understanding of what the code is actually doing.

```
// myVar is declared undefined
var myVar;
// you call console.log with undefined
console.log(myVar);
// sometime later .then is called
myModule.myFunction().then(function(data){
   // later you set the global variable to the data
   myVar = data;
   // at this point you can log the value of myVar 
});
```

In terms of returning something from an ajax call you can't do it synchronously, but you can chain another `.then` after it's returned.

```
myModule.myFunction().then(function(data){
   // do something with the data
   return data; 
})
.then(function(data){
   // do something else with the data
})
```

You can keep chaining `then` as long as you want, and there are more useful methods you can use for error handling, or calling promises in parallel or synchronously

Answer (score 0):

Because `then` is asynchronous, `console.log` will be called before `then`, so at the time of the log, it is `undefined`.

This will give you the result you're after:

```
var myVar;    
myModule.myFunction().then(function(data){
    myVar = data; 
    console.log(myVar);  
});
```

Comment: Downvoters, why have you downvoted this answer and (presumably) the two other answers?

Comment: Great question! All three are correct! Upvoting all back!